# wtforms, ndb and blobstore

Tags: blobstore, app-engine-ndb, wtforms

I have this model:

```
class Product(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    description = ndb.TextProperty()
    img = ndb.BlobKeyProperty(indexed=False)
```

I need a html form that reads the values ​​of fields (title and description) and read the image (from a file field), and keeps the values ​​NDB object, the image in the Blobstore and updates the field BlobKeyProperty correctly.

As I work with wtforms, I tried to do it with a form like the following:

```
class ProductForm(Form):
    title = fields.TextField('Title', [validators.Required(), validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
    description = fields.TextAreaField('Description')
    img = fields.FileField('img')
```

The form shows the file field correctly but in the POST, it does not work because I don't know how to read the file, save the file to Blobstore and update the BlobKeyProperty.

My handler is this:

```
class ProductHandler(BaseHandler):
    def new(self):
        if self.request.POST:
            data = ProductForm(self.request.POST)
            if data.validate():
                model = Product()
                data.populate_obj(model)
                model.put()
                self.add_message("Product add!", 'success')
                return self.redirect_to("product-list")
            else:
                self.add_message("Product not add!", 'error')
        params = {
            'form': ProductForm(),
            "kind": "product",
        }
        return self.render_template('admin/new.html', **params)
```

Error is Expected str, got u'image.jpg'

If someone can help me, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to use a **deprecated** low-level API described in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Writing_files_to_the_Blobstore

I make a wtform validator for the FileField.

I changed:

```
img = fields.FileField('img')
```

To:

```
img = fields.FileField('img', [create_upload_file])
```

And I write this validator:

```
def create_upload_file(form, field):
    file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type=field.data.type, _blobinfo_uploaded_filename=field.data.filename)
    with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
        f.write(field.data.file.read())
    files.finalize(file_name)
    blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
    field.data = blob_key
```

The validator create the blob in blobstore, and then it change the field data from FieldStorage to blob_key.

I don't think that is the best solution but it works for now.